# Ignore deleted messages by the bot

Tags: javascript, discord.js

So I am working on a deleted messages log. I got it to work, but the messages that get deleted by the bot are getting logged too. And not 1 time. I get like 5 of the same deleted message. I already tried something like `if(!messageDelete.author.bot) {}` but after trying it still logs the bots deleted messages and still creates 10 of it. Here is the code I am currently using:

```
bot.on("messageDelete", (messageDelete) => {
  if(!messageDelete.author.bot) {
    let DeleteEmbed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
    .setTitle("**DELETED MESSAGE OWO**")
    .setColor("#ed0c75")
    .addField("Author", messageDelete.author.tag, true)
    .addField("Channel", messageDelete.channel, true)
    .addField("Message", messageDelete.content)
    .setFooter(`Message ID: ${messageDelete.id} | Author ID: ${messageDelete.author.id}`, messageDelete.author.displayAvatar);

    let DeleteChannel = messageDelete.guild.channels.find(x => x.name === "mod-logs");
    DeleteChannel.send(DeleteEmbed);
}})
```

and here is a screenshot of the output. For example, if I use the *purge* command it logs all deleted messages.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9zAg1.png)

I hope someone can help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

To do this, you need to look at `audit logs` in Discord, the audit logs show both the executor and the victim (I don't know what to call it).

To look at the deleted message audit logs you use:

```
let logs = await messageDelete.guild.fetchAuditLogs({
        type: 72
    });
```

Then to look at the most recent:

```
let entry = logs.entries.first();
```

Then to check if the bot deleted a message and what to do (And if it didn't):

```
if (entry.executor.username === bot.user.username) {
        return;
    } else {
        let DeleteEmbed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
    .setTitle("**DELETED MESSAGE OWO**")
    .setColor("#ed0c75")
    .addField("Author", messageDelete.author.tag, true)
    .addField("Channel", messageDelete.channel, true)
    .addField("Message", messageDelete.content)
    .setFooter(`Message ID: ${messageDelete.id} | Author ID: ${messageDelete.author.id}`, messageDelete.author.displayAvatar);

    let DeleteChannel = messageDelete.guild.channels.find(x => x.name === "mod-logs");
    DeleteChannel.send(DeleteEmbed);
    };
```

All of this code together looks like this:

```
let logs = await messageDelete.guild.fetchAuditLogs({
        type: 72
    });
let entry = logs.entries.first();
if (entry.executor.username === bot.user.username) {
        return;
    } else {
        let DeleteEmbed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
    .setTitle("**DELETED MESSAGE OWO**")
    .setColor("#ed0c75")
    .addField("Author", messageDelete.author.tag, true)
    .addField("Channel", messageDelete.channel, true)
    .addField("Message", messageDelete.content)
    .setFooter(`Message ID: ${messageDelete.id} | Author ID: ${messageDelete.author.id}`, messageDelete.author.displayAvatar);

    let DeleteChannel = messageDelete.guild.channels.find(x => x.name === "mod-logs");
    DeleteChannel.send(DeleteEmbed);
    };
```

I hope this helped answer your question!

P.S - Nice bot name.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try replacing `!messageDelete.author.bot` by `message.author != bot.user`

Comment: Thanks for the help, it worked, it doesn't log the purge command anymore, so that's a good thing! Somehow he is still logging the deleted message like 5 times, but at least 1 problem solved.